# Sphinx domain for Clojure

Tags: clojure, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm used to working with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for C++ and Python projects.  I've just started a project in [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) and I'd like to re-use my Sphinx/reStructuredText skills to document my Clojure code.  Since there's no built-in [domain](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html) for Clojure, I started writing one.

Ironically, Sphinx's documentation is of no help at all for writing extensions.  So, starting from the built-in modes for Python and Javascript, I've got some basic elements working.  I can write document for functions using the following directives:

```
.. clj:ns:: clojure.core

.. clj:fn:: (filter f coll)

   :param f: predicate
   :param coll: collection

   Built-in!
```

However, the HTML output produces C/Python-style signatures.  The preceding example generates something like this:

```
filter(f, coll)

    Parameters: * f - predicate
                * coll - collection

    Built-in!
```

I'd much rather get the signature in the lisp-ish form as:

```
(filter f coll)

    Parameters: * f - predicate
                * coll - collection

    Built-in!
```

The code that generates the signatures seems to go all the way down to `docutils.addnodes` module.  How can I make Sphinx generate the HTML using the Sphinx syntax?  Can it be done with a template, or do I need hack my way through the whole builder system to do this?

Comment: Did you check Erlang domain in sphinx-contrib?

Comment: Yes, I did.  There is no mention of how to format the resulting signature.  The rendering is done deep in Sphinx (`sphinx.builders.html.py`, `class HTMLTranslator`).  It seems you need to write your own HTML builder to render the output.  Now, how on earth am I going to document multiple languages in the same project?

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I'm trying to integrate a clojure project with an existing project using sphinx, but haven't found a sphinx domain for clojure.

Comment: @user1009908: As explained in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5736906/313063), I tried writing my own extension and could not get anything reasonable to get work because it involved changes to core Sphinx elements which are not accessible to plug-ins.  As this was over 3 years ago, maybe things have improved in Sphinx to make this possible.  Then again, maybe the Sphinx community has created something better for documenting Clojure code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the current version (1.0.7), changing how the signature is formatted involves extending the `HTMLTranslator` class in Sphinx (`sphinx/writers/html.py`).  However, there is no domain-specific handling at this level, changes for Clojure signatures will affect signatures on other domains too.